# Creating a new style of title

Tags: titles, draw

I was wondering if anyone could provide a code that would produce a title for a document similar to the one shown below.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very 'basic' setup as a table and injecting it into the page header with `fancyhdr`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[headheight=15pt]{geometry}

\newcounter{week}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.3}
\newcommand{\myniceheader}{%
\refstepcounter{week}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XcX}
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-3} 
&  \multirow{5}{*}{\bfseries Problems of Week \theweek} & \tabularnewline
\cline{1-1}  \cline{3-3}  \tabularnewline
\cline{1-1}  \cline{3-3}  \tabularnewline
\cline{1-1}  \cline{3-3}  \tabularnewline
\cline{1-1}  \cline{3-3}  
\end{tabularx}}



\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \chead{\myniceheader}
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}

\blindtext[20]



\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update with array rule colour and control of the thickness of rules**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[headheight=28pt]{geometry}

\newcounter{week}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.3}
\newcommand{\myniceheader}{%
\refstepcounter{week}
\begingroup
\arrayrulecolor{blue}
\renewcommand{\arrayrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XcX}
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-3} 
&  \multirow{5}{*}{\bfseries Problems of Week \theweek} & \tabularnewline
\cline{1-1}  \cline{3-3}  \tabularnewline
\cline{1-1}  \cline{3-3}  \tabularnewline
\cline{1-1}  \cline{3-3}  \tabularnewline
\cline{1-1}  \cline{3-3}  
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup
}



\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \chead{\myniceheader}
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}

\blindtext[20]



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way one can change the color and thickness of the lines, also?

Comment: @wrb98: See the update at the bottom please (sorry for the delay!)

Comment: Christian Hupfer- Please, how make to appear only the word Problems (no counter), to be placed at the end of each chapter, opening the sequence of problems?

Comment: @benedito: Unclear. Please ask a new question for this.