# How to define a specific macro?

Tags: formatting

In [Creating a new style of title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348156/creating-the-new-style-of-title), how can I create a macro to achieve this:

[image]

I want to use it at the end each chapter of a book.

Comment: Well, in the linked question there's an answer by me and I have shown just one of many possibilities to generate such 'headings'

Comment: Christian Hupfer - I don't think I made my point. Precisely, there's a simple way to put the drawing at the end of each chapter without having to put all commands that generate the nice design you did?

Comment: It's just copying the definition of `\myniceheader` into the document or a personal `.sty` file and doing something similar what Heiko Oberdiek has done with his `\EndChapter` macro. It's LaTeX, not Quantum Field Theory ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width of the rules can be calculated by measuring the width of the text and subtracting it from the line width.

The lines can be drawn by rules stacked in `\vcenter`, which centers the contents around the math axis.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand*{\EndChapter}[1]{%
  \par
  \noindent
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{\bfseries\ #1\ }%
    \dimen0=.5\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd0\relax
    \BlueLines{\dimen0}%
    \usebox0%
    \BlueLines{\dimen0}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\BlueLines}[1]{%
  $%
    \mathsurround=0pt %
    \color{blue}%
    \vcenter{%
      \hrule width#1 height\BlueLinesThickness
      \kern\BlueLinesSep
      \hrule width#1 height\BlueLinesThickness
      \kern\BlueLinesSep
      \hrule width#1 height\BlueLinesThickness
      \kern\BlueLinesSep
      \hrule width#1 height\BlueLinesThickness
      \kern\BlueLinesSep
      \hrule width#1 height\BlueLinesThickness
    }%
  $%
}
\newdimen\BlueLinesThickness
\setlength{\BlueLinesThickness}{2pt}
\newdimen\BlueLinesSep
\setlength{\BlueLinesSep}{1.5pt}

\begin{document}
\EndChapter{Problems of Week 1}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Heiko Oberdiek. Ok. It works!